# How to join a subqueries during leftjoin using query builder laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

```
$productLists = DB::table('A')
                    ->leftJoin('B', function($join) {
                        $join->where('B.qty','=', 1);
                        $join->on("B.id", "=", "A.id");
                    })
                    ->select('A.*','B.*')
                    ->get();
```

What's wrong with the query?

The field I get from B table all returned `null` .

Am I doing it in wrong way?

Comment: I would put `->where('B.qty','=', 1)`outside `leftJoin` callback

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$productLists = DB::table('A')
               ->leftJoin('B', function($join) {
                      $join->where('B.qty','=', 1)
                           ->on("B.id", "=", "A.id");
               })
               ->select('A.*','B.*')
               ->get();
```

Comment: Just posting code is not a good answer.  Describe what you did and why you think it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$productLists = DB::table('A') ->select('A.*','B.*')->join('B','B.id','=','A.id')->where('B.qty', 1) ->get();
```

this is one way to write joins in laravel..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$productLists = DB::table('A')
                  ->join('B', 'B.id', '=', 'A.id')
                  ->select('A.*','B.*')
                  ->where('B.qty','=', 1)
                  ->get();
```